# How to add a distinct scroll bar for a left menu inside my page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a scroll bar to the searchable menu on the left that is **fixed** as it must only scroll for its own items.

This scroll must be specific to this left menu and must NOT scroll the actual main page content:

Please find a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaMC0.png) of the page with its left menu.

Comment: This is from W3school with the link below: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_search_menu.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the markup you provided, you could set a specific `height` and add `overflow:auto;` on the sidebar with class `.left`.

**See the modification below and run the snippet.**

```
.left {
  flex: 35%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  height:400px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create a column layout with Flexbox */
.row {
  display: flex;
}

/* Left column (menu) */
.left {
  flex: 35%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  height:400px;
  overflow:auto;
}

.left h2 {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

/* Right column (page content) */
.right {
  flex: 65%;
  padding: 15px;
}

/* Style the search box */
#mySearch {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

/* Style the navigation menu inside the left column */
#myMenu {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myMenu li a {
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myMenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Search Menu</h2>
  <p>Start to type for a specific category inside the search bar to "filter" the search options.</p>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="left" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <h2>Menu</h2>
      <input type="text" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a category">
      <ul id="myMenu">
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SQL</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Node.js</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SQL</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Node.js</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Python</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SQL</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bootstrap</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Node.js</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="right" style="background-color:#ddd;">
      <h2>Page Content</h2>
      <p>Start to type for a specific category inside the search bar to "filter" the search options.</p>
      <p>Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..</p>
      <p>Some other text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..Some text..</p>
      <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myMenu");
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```